# What is SQL query of retrieving entries whose specific column has same values?

Tags: sql, row

Lets assume I have following Database table

```
id Name
1  X
2  X
3  X
4  Y
5  Z
6  Z
```

What I want to do is to retrieve rows whose Name column have same values, no matter what specifically Name is. In other words name will not be entered in SQL query.

Result table:

```
id Name
1  X
2  X
3  X
5  Z
6  Z
```

What should be SQL for this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  Name
            FROM    TableName
            GROUP   BY Name
            HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
        ) b ON b.Name = a.Name
```

using `IN` (*although I prefer JOIN*)

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tableName
WHERE   Name IN
        (
            SELECT  Name
            FROM    TableName
            GROUP   BY Name
            HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
        )
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*both queries included*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6bc2e1/2)